# R: Plotting a bar graph

Tags: r

I have a table like the following:

```
Variable_Name , Value
A, 2
B, 7
```

I want to plot a bar graph where A has a Y value of 2 and B has a Y value of 7.

However, the graph I'm getting from the following code has both bars with a length of 1:

```
 bar_chart <- ggplot(table_name, aes(x=Variable_Name))+geom_bar()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `geom_col` or `geom_bar(stat = 'identity')`

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(table_name, aes(x=Variable_Name, Value))+ geom_col()
```

[image]